# Drag and Drop an element which is not part of the same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to drag the clone the element id="btn" and drop it into the div class="ui-layout-content". I'm able to drag and drop elements from one div to another which are under a container. But I'm not able to do the same between divisions which are not part of the same container. Here is my code:

```
<div class="ui-layout-west">
  <h3 class="hdr">Drag and Drop Toolbar</h3>
  <div class="ui-layout-content">
    <div id=“btn”>button</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mainContent">
  <div class="ui-layout-center">
    <h3 class="hdr">Design Area</h3>
    <div class="ui-layout-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your code didn't make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery UI Draggable and you can have something like this:

```
var is_Over_Right_Element = false;
$( "#dropHere" ).mouseover(function() { 
    is_Over_Right_Element = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Either set the position to *absolute* on the div element that is "draggable".

OR

Set the other window as the new parent element.

```
$("#btnCLONE").appendTo("#someOtherDiv");
```

If everything fails. Put both areas into one large "draggable" container and add a **mouseover** event listener that checks that you are hovering over the right area to be able to drop the clone in.

```
    var is_Over_Right_Element = false;
    $( "#dropHere" ).mouseover(function() { 
        is_Over_Right_Element = true;
    });
```